# How to get the id a symlink is pointing at in the symlink's template?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

This is pretty hard to explain...

In modX Revolution, I'm trying to get the symlink's "Symlink" field in the template to use it in a snippet (the id the symlink is pointing at).

The suggestion when I mouseover that field is `[[*content]]`, but when using that I get the actual content of the page I'm pointing at with the symlink.

Any suggestions? The documentation doesn't help, and I've been google-ing it for an hour now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this is the expected behavior for a symlink.

I just fired up a little test on my testing server and here is the result:

getResource (install it from Package Management) returns no symlink:

If 6 is the id of the symlink pointing to a page with the id of 10:

`[[!getResources? &resources=`6`]]`

will return:

```
Array (
    [id] => 6
    [type] => document
    [contentType] => text/html
    [pagetitle] => My Symlink
    [alias] => my-symlink
    [link_attributes] => 
    [published] => 1
    [parent] => 0
    [isfolder] => 
    [introtext] => 
    [content] => 
    [richtext] => 
    [template] => 1
    [menuindex] => 2
    [searchable] => 1
    [cacheable] => 1
    [createdby] => 1
    [createdon] => 2011-03-25 09:43:31
    [editedby] => 1
    [editedon] => 2011-03-25 09:57:30
    [deleted] => 
    [deletedon] => 0
    [deletedby] => 0
    [publishedon] => 2011-03-25 09:43:00
    [publishedby] => 1
    [menutitle] => 
)
```

Please note that the content key is empty.

User lkossis on MODx Forums suggests another approach: using a snippet to get the `[[*content]]` value.

```
$id= isset($id) && intval($id) ? intval($id) : $modx->resource->get('id');
$field = isset($field) ? $field : 'id';

$thisDocument=$modx->getDocument($id);
return $thisDocument[$field];
```

And in your template:

```
[[!getDocumentField? &field=`content`]]
```

The credit goes to lkossis on MODx Forums.
http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,61784.msg351101.html#msg351101